# Database insertion synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have a java code that generates a request number  based on the data received from database, and then updates the database for newly generated

```
synchronized (this.getClass()) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(counter);
            System.out.println("start " + System.identityHashCode(this));
            certRequest
                    .setRequestNbr(generateRequestNumber(certInsuranceRequestAddRq
                            .getAccountInfo().getAccountNumberId()));
            System.out.println("outside funcvtion"+certRequest.getRequestNbr());
            reqId = Utils.getUniqueId();
            certRequest.setRequestId(reqId);
            System.out.println(reqId);
            ItemIdInfo itemIdInfo = new ItemIdInfo();

            itemIdInfo.setInsurerId(certRequest.getRequestId());

            certRequest.setItemIdInfo(itemIdInfo);

            dao.insert(certRequest);
            addAccountRel();
            counter++;
            System.out.println(counter);
            System.out.println("end");

        }
```

the output for System.out.println() statements is `

```
1
start 27907101
com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.CertRequest@a042cb
inside function request number66
outside funcvtion66
AF88172D-C8B0-4DCD-9AC6-12296EF8728D

2
end
3
start 21695531
com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.CertRequest@f98690
inside function request number66
outside funcvtion66
F3200106-6033-4AEC-8DC3-B23FCD3CA380

4
end
```

In my case I get a call from two threads for this code.

If you observe both the threads run independently. However the data for request number is same in both the cases.

is it possible that before the database updation for first thread completes the second thread starts execution. 
`
the code for generateRequestNumber() is  as follows:

public String generateRequestNumber(String accNumber) throws Exception {

```
String requestNumber = null;

if (accNumber != null) {

    String SQL_QUERY = "select CERTREQUEST.requestNbr from CertRequest as CERTREQUEST, "
            + "CertActObjRel  as certActObjRel where  certActObjRel.certificateObjkeyId=CERTREQUEST.requestId "
            + " and certActObjRel.certObjTypeCd=:certObjTypeCd "
            + " and certActObjRel.certAccountId=:accNumber ";

    String[] parameterNames = { "certObjTypeCd", "accNumber" };
    Object[] parameterVaues = new Object[] {
            Constants.REQUEST_RELATION_CODE, accNumber };
    List<?> resultSet = dao.executeNamedQuery(SQL_QUERY,
            parameterNames, parameterVaues);

    // List<?> resultSet = dao.retrieveTableData(SQL_QUERY);
    if (resultSet != null && resultSet.size() > 0) {
        requestNumber = (String) resultSet.get(0);
    }

    int maxRequestNumber = -1;

    if (requestNumber != null && requestNumber.length() > 0) {
        maxRequestNumber = maxValue(resultSet.toArray());
        requestNumber = Integer.toString(maxRequestNumber + 1);

    } else {
        requestNumber = Integer.toString(1);
    }
    System.out.println("inside function request number"+requestNumber);
    return requestNumber;
}
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases allow multiple simultaneous connections, so unless you write your code properly you can mess up the data.

Since you only seem to require a unique growing integer, you can easily generate one safely inside the database with for example a sequence (if supported by the database). Databases not supporting sequences usually provide some other way (such as auto increment columns in MySQL).

Comment: I got your point, however I don't just require unique growing integer, first I need to update two database tables and then based on that updation again generate the next number.

Comment: @pkn1230 In your example the number that follows 66 is 67. Doesn't sound like too much logic in generating that number.

Comment: Please ignore it, it was a old output.

Comment: Well, you may want to modify your `generateRequestNumber` so it's thread-safe. The code you're displaying doesn't really tell anything. You left out all the actual implementation.

Comment: I suppose I have a transaction synchronisation issue.